# API design and impl: receive a specific type and return instance from an object array

Tags: java

In `org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint` we can do this `Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();`

Now, I want to implement an API that can achieve this:

```
// This method receive a variable which can help me know which type of instance he want
public String getInstanceStr(JoinPoint joinPoint, ??customerType??/*?how to design here?*/){
    String requestStr = null;
    Object[] os = joinPoint.getArgs();
    for (int i = 0; i < os.length; i++) {
        /*?How to determine the type here?*/
        if (os[i] instanceof ??cusomerType??) {
            requestStr = os[i].toString();
        }
    }
    return requestStr;
}
```

Then, the caller can do this:

```
ClientMethod(){
    String str = API.getInstanceStr(joinPoint, ??customerType??);
}
```

In this case, client can determine what to fetch from args.

I have tried `Class` and `<T>`, as you can see, I failed.

Please tell me whether or how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
    // This method receive a variable which can help me know which type of instance he want
    public String getInstanceStr(JoinPoint joinPoint, Class<? extends Object> clazz){
        String requestStr = null;
        Object[] os = joinPoint.getArgs();
        for (int i = 0; i < os.length; i++) {
            /*?How to determine the type here?*/
             if(clazz.isInstance(os[i])){
                requestStr = os[i].toString();
            }

        }
        return requestStr;
    }
```